# Performance drop in SceneKit with custom Metal shader

Tags: scenekit, metal

I have scene with 4000 objects (1000 objects are visible), all using same material (via assigning custom created SCNGeometry's firstMaterial property to same SCNMaterial object) running at 60FPS (1000 draw calls, 150k triangles, Metal flush ~12ms).

Now I want to change rendering my material. Using shader modifier all works fine, performance is the same, but I need to completely replace SceneKit's rendering, so I am using SCNProgram with Metal vertex and fragment shaders (tried both very basic and dumped SceneKit's default shaders). When I assign that program to my material everything works as expected, except huge performance drop - statistics shows 20FPS, 4000 draw calls, 600K triangles, Metal flush ~30ms.

So, it seems that some work done several times. Maybe some one have idea where's the root of problem can be?

**EDIT:**

It seems I narrowed problem. This affects both OpenGL and Metal shaders: I'm loosing frustum culling when using custom `SCNProgram`. In default SceneKit Metal shader I see:

```
typedef struct {
...
#ifdef USE_BOUNDINGBOX
float2x3 boundingBox;
#endif
...
} commonprofile_node;
```

Which is passed to vertex and fragment shader, but is not used anywhere. Since default shader does not have frustum culling code, then perhaps it should be done elsewhere.

Comment: Little known fact, SceneKit and SpriteKit in iOS 9 are broken.

Comment: @Confused but i am on mac os x, that applies too?

Comment: much more broken on Mac... pre-alpha

Comment: Is this related to the switch from OpenGL to Metal as the foundation for SceneKit/SpriteKit in iOS 9/El Cap?

Comment: @Hal Mueller, please see edited post.